# scanimage: open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:[s/n] failed: Invalid argument

Tags: sane

Trying to trigger scans from fujitsu ScanSnap iX500 using CLI, defining a specific scanner.

`scanimage --device 'fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:[s/n]' --resolution 300 --batch=Scan-p%d.pnm --format=pnm --mode color`

The error from that: scanimage: *open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:[s/n] failed: Invalid argument*

The --device entry was derived from `sudo scanimage -L`
The following variations of --device return the same error:

- `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500`
- `fujitsu:ScanSnap`
- `fujitsu`

Removing the `--device` option removes the error, BUT causes the command to search for a locally-attached device, which introduces a long delay.  Targeting the --device in the hopes of eliminating the delay.

Answer (score 0):

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/scanimage : there is no parameter "`--device`" for the scanimage command.

Maybe you want to use `-d` or `--device-name` and follow the advices given in the manual:

> The -d or --device-name options must be followed by a SANE device-name like 'epson:/dev/sg0' or 'hp:/dev/usbscanner0'. A (partial) list of available devices can be obtained with the --list-devices option (see below). If no device-name is specified explicitly, scanimage reads a device-name from the environment variable SANE_DEFAULT_DEVICE. If this variable is not set, scanimage will attempt to open the first available device.

Comment: Thanks jhecn, I'd seen that too, sometimes `--device-name`, sometimes `--device`, sometimes `-d` used in different contexts.  It turns out they're all valid, and mean the same thing.  (The giveaway is in the error: `open of device fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:[s/n] failed: Invalid argument` -- suggesting a) It knows it's going after a 'device'.  b) It doesn't recognize the device given.)

Comment: The actual problem turned out to be permissions.  If you run it as suggested by the SANE documentation, under their .sh file, all works fine.  But attempting the commands listed in that .sh file directly in command line failed -- presumably because the CLI is running under a different user than the .sh file.  I haven't worked out the details.  The bottom line: It looks like a device problem, but it's really a permissions issue.

Comment: The solution, in my case was to simply add `sudo` before the command -- problem solved.  Will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, it turns out, was not in the naming of the device.  (The name returned by `sudo scanimage -L` is the correct one to use and works fine.

The issue has to do with permissions / user

Running the command under the .sh file used appropriate permissions.  Running directly in command line must have used another user, even though both were executed under the same ssh session.

Solution: Choose the right login user.  In my case adding `sudo` before the command (which was not included or necessary in the .sh file) resolved the issue.